# Convert NL equality constraint involving minimum to linear inequality constraint?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research, constraints

Is it possible to convert an equality constraint involving the minimum, to a linear inequality constraint?

Suppose I have an optimization problem which involves the variables $x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3$, with the constraint
\begin{equation}
x_1 =\min(x_2,\,x_3)\;.
\end{equation}
I would like to convert it to a standard linear inequality constraint. My naive attempt was
\begin{equation}
x_1 =\min(x_2,\,x_3) \to x_1 \leq \min(x_2,\,x_3)\, \land\, x_1 \geq \min(x_2,\,x_3) 
\end{equation}
Then,
\begin{equation}
x_1 \leq \min(x_2,\,x_3) \to x_1 \leq x_2 \land x_1 \leq x_3\;.
\end{equation}
But I am stuck with 
\begin{equation}
 x_1 \geq \min(x_2,\,x_3)\;, 
\end{equation}
which I don't know how to linearize.

Comment: Erwin's answer is correct for any objective function. If the nature of your problem is such that larger values of $x_1$ are always better (all other variables fixed), you can omit the lower limit on $x_1$ (and thus avoid turning the problem into an integer program).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constraint
$$ z = \min(x,y) $$
can be interpreted as:
$$
\begin{align}
 &z \le x \text{ and } z \le y\\
 &z \ge x \text{ or } z \ge y
\end{align}
$$
This can be implemented in a MIP model using a big-$M$ formulation:
$$
\begin{align}
 &z \le x\\
 &z \le y\\
 &z \ge x - M\delta\\
 &z \ge y - M(1-\delta)\\
 &\delta \in \{0,1\} 
\end{align}
$$
where $M$ is a large enough constant.

Advanced solvers have capabilities that can provide alternative approaches, such as

- SOS1 variables
- indicator constraints
- direct implementation of $z=\min(x,y)$ using general constraints

Comment: thank you for your answer. Would you please recommend some books or maybe links for linearization techniques ?